# Spark GroupBy Aggregate functions

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, aggregate-functions, apache-spark-dataset

```
case class Step (Id : Long,
                 stepNum : Long,
                 stepId : Int,
                 stepTime: java.sql.Timestamp
                 )
```

I have a Dataset[Step] and I want to perform a groupBy operation on the "Id" col.
My output should look like Dataset[(Long, List[Step])]. How do I do this?

lets say variable "inquiryStepMap" is of type Dataset[Step] then we can do this with RDDs as follows

```
val inquiryStepGrouped: RDD[(Long, Iterable[Step])] = inquiryStepMap.rdd.groupBy(x => x.Id)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need `groupByKey`:

Sample:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp    
val t = new Timestamp(2017, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)    
val ds = Seq(Step(1L, 21L, 1, t), Step(1L, 20L, 2, t), Step(2L, 10L, 3, t)).toDS()
```

---

`groupByKey` and then `mapGroups`:

```
ds.groupByKey(_.Id).mapGroups((Id, Vals) => (Id, Vals.toList))
// res18: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[(Long, List[Step])] = [_1: bigint, _2: array<struct<Id:bigint,stepNum:bigint,stepId:int,stepTime:timestamp>>]
```

And the result looks like:

```
ds.groupByKey(_.Id).mapGroups((Id, Vals) => (Id, Vals.toList)).show()
+---+--------------------+
| _1|                  _2|
+---+--------------------+
|  1|[[1,21,1,3917-06-...|
|  2|[[2,10,3,3917-06-...|
+---+--------------------+
```